RuntimeError: Failed raising error. Mysql-connector-python
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=ip,
            user=user,
            password=password)

Hello. I use mysql-connector-python https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python
When i run this code on my PC everything fine (Python 3.12)
But when i try to execute this on other PC, it gives me this error RuntimeError: Failed raising error
BUT. when i change the ip to 127.0.0.1 or just not neccessary ip it gives just an error that i type wrong host.
I tried to execute this on different python version since 3.10 to 3.13 and on 3.10 it said
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
I use Pycharm
I tried to change python versions, start pycharm with admin rights, reinstall libary
(Update)
When i use venv from other project, everything works fine

What is the value of ip in your PC?

@YannisP. 31.128.37.77

When running this code on your PC, don't you set ip=127.0.0.1?

The RuntimeError can also be many things. I am not sure we can help you, but try posting the full message that is printed when you run the script. [Edit] your message and add the full error message.

@YannisP. can this error be because of cirilic symbols in system folders?

Reason was that i installed Python at path with cirilic symbols, when i installed it at other path, everything started work fine
